# how do I use ssh with key access in 11.10

Tags: ssh, authentication

I've used ssh before and password access from my new asus k53by laptop with a fresh 11.10 install to dev server works fine.

I wanted to set up key access for added security and ease of scripting and I did the following:

```
paul@paul-K53BY:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/paul/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/paul/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/paul/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
7e:91:b2:2b:a9:bc:f8:11:d1:aa:ea:41:c5:1a:39:ff paul@paul-K53BY
paul@paul-K53BY:~/.ssh$ ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub 10.1.1.28
paul@10.1.1.28's password:
```

Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh '10.1.1.28'", and check in:

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

```
paul@paul-K53BY:~/.ssh$ ssh 10.1.1.28
paul@10.1.1.28's password:
```

- Everything seemed to work but I still needed to use the password. I also wanted a convenient handle for the server (without the hassle of DNS) so I set up ~/.ssh/config as follows:

  ```
  Host dev

  HostName 10.1.1.28
  PasswordAuthentication no
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  ```
- ssh dev
  then failed:

  ```
  paul@paul-K53BY:~/.ssh$ ssh dev
  Permission denied (publickey,password).
  ```
- Switching password back on showed that ssh dev works fine still with the password.

  ```
  paul@paul-K53BY:~/.ssh$ ssh -vvv dev
  OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
  debug1: Reading configuration data /home/paul/.ssh/config
  debug1: Applying options for dev
  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
  debug1: Applying options for *
  debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
  debug1: Connecting to 10.1.1.28 [10.1.1.28] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
  debug3: Could not load "/home/paul/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
  debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
  debug3: key_read: missing keytype
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
  debug3: key_read: missing keytype
  debug1: identity file /home/paul/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
  debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
  debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
  debug1: identity file /home/paul/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/paul/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/paul/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/paul/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/paul/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
  debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7 pat OpenSSH*
  debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
  debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.1.1.28" from file "/home/paul/.ssh/known_hosts"
  debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/paul/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
  debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
  debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
  debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
  debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
  debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
  debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 123/256
  debug2: bits set: 500/1024
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
  debug1: Server host key: RSA eb:f9:56:b8:ae:b0:de:27:92:06:8f:ac:c1:43:e4:64
  debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.1.1.28" from file "/home/paul/.ssh/known_hosts"
  debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/paul/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
  debug1: Host '10.1.1.28' is known and matches the RSA host key.
  debug1: Found key in /home/paul/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  debug2: bits set: 511/1024
  debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
  debug2: kex_derive_keys
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
  debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug2: key: /home/paul/.ssh/id_rsa (0xb9434eb0)
  debug2: key: /home/paul/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
  debug2: key: /home/paul/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
  debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
  debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
  debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
  debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/paul/.ssh/id_rsa
  debug3: send_pubkey_test
  debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/paul/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug3: no such identity: /home/paul/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/paul/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug3: no such identity: /home/paul/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
  debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
  Permission denied (publickey,password).
  ```

All that output is telling me something but I'm not sure what. What have I done wrong and why can't I get this ssh by key to work?

There seem to be quite a few questions here about 11.10 ssh/key access issues but I could not see anything I could try anywhere that might solve this for me.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't seem to recognise your key file as a valid key. Are both files present and in the .ssh directory?

Comment: Yes, and both are readable.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly,**

> debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
>
> debug3: Could not load "/home/paul/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
>
> debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'

A public key does not start with the '-----BEGIN' words. Those are the words found in a private key.

**Secondly,** are you sure that this worked:

> paul@paul-K53BY:~/.ssh$ ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub 10.1.1.28

try:

> ssh-copy-id 10.1.1.28

(this will default to ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. I am not sure if the complete path is required or not).

**Thirdly,** is your home folder on the server encrypted? If it is, then you need to physically log in on the server and keep this session open at all times. Then, when you ssh from your machine to the server, the ssh keys will be automatically used

Comment: Tried ssh-copy-id 10.1.1.28 and it made no difference. I'm still always prompted for the password :( The information about the key is interesting though. It sounds like that might be the issue although I just copy pasted the standard instructions so I don't know what can have happened.

Comment: is your home folder on the server encrypted? if it is, then you need to physically log in on the server and keep this session open at all times. Then, when you ssh from your machine to the server, the ssh keys will be automatically used.

Comment: @Whippy Does this answer solve your issues? If yes, please do accept the answer or if you already have solved your problem, add that as an answer and accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: The home folder is not encrypted on either machine.